# Is there a way to programmatically create a gif from a mo.js animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, gif, animated-gif

I just want to programmatically create a gif from a very simple mo.js animation like this:

```
const burst = new mojs.Burst({
    radius: {0:300},
    children: {
        shape: 'rect',
        duration: 3000
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You might be better off with another lib and animate on canvas, then convert it to gif.

Comment: And what are you stuck ? What is your question exactly ?

Comment: @Elikill58 I am looking for a library with which I can programmatically create a gif file from a mo.js animation. All tools I have found so far require a canvas to create a gif.

Comment: @code do you have a suggestion with which framework i can create a burst animation in a similarly simple way as with mo.js?